# Get value from Async task in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class as shown below. It is in a .java file called NQRequestHandler.java and I want to call this from an Activity.java. But I'm having problems with the AsyncTask method. When I run it in the Activity.java file it returns a null 
value when I try to log the value of `Globals.PUBLIC_KEY` from the Activity. 
Log.v("RESULT", "Public KEY JSON from OnStart" + Globals.PUBLIC_KEY);

```
public class NQRequestHandler {

    private static NQRequestHandler instance;
    public static final String TAG = NQRequestHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext;


public NQRequestHandler(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public static synchronized NQRequestHandler getInstance(Context context) {

    if (instance == null)
        instance = new NQRequestHandler(context);

    return instance;
}

public class requestHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

    RequestListener requestListener;
    public JSONArray requestResult;

    public requestHandler() {

    }

    public void setRequestListener(RequestListener requestListener) {
        this.requestListener = requestListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            String url = "http://www.someurl.com";

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = requestHandlerHelper(params);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);

            entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));
            post.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

            int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength();
            Log.v(TAG, "Content Length DATA" + contentLength);
            char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
            reader.read(charArray);

            String responseData = new String(charArray);
            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(responseData);

            return jsonResponse;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ClientProtocolException: ", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException: ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "IOException: ", e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "JSONException: ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray results) {
        if (results != null) {
            requestListener.onRequestSuccess(results);
        } else {
            requestListener.onRequestFailed();
        }
    }

}

public interface RequestListener {
    JSONArray onRequestSuccess(JSONArray data);

    void onRequestFailed();
}

public void NQRequest(String... params) {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        requestHandler handler = new requestHandler();
        RequestListener listener = new RequestListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public JSONArray onRequestSuccess(JSONArray data) {
                //TODO: Switch set data here

                Log.v(TAG, "JSON FROM NQRequest" + data);
                Globals.PUBLIC_KEY = String.valueOf(data);
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network is unavailable. Request failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        handler.setRequestListener(listener);
        handler.execute(params);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private static List<NameValuePair> requestHandlerHelper(String... params) {

    //Declare URL Parameter values
    List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String[] requestActionArray = Globals.REQUEST_ACTION_ID;
    int actionSwitch = -1;
    String[] requestActionHeaders = null;

    //Find URL Parameter Action Switch
    for (int i = 0; i < requestActionArray.length; i++) {
        if (requestActionArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase(params[params.length - 1])) {
            actionSwitch = i;
        }
    }

    //Set Action Switch ID Parameters
    requestActionHeaders = NQActionHeader(actionSwitch);

    //Set URL Parameters
    for (int i = 0; i < requestActionHeaders.length; i++) {
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(requestActionHeaders[i], params[i]));
    }

    return urlParameters;
}

private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager manager =
            (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() ? true : false;
}

private static String[] NQActionHeader(int actionSwitch) {
    /* some code goes here */
    }
}
```

In the Activity class looks like this:

```
public class Application extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        String message = "Hello World from Android";
            Context mContext = getBaseContext();
            NQRequestHandler.requestHandler handler = new     NQRequestHandler.requestHandler();
            NQRequestHandler requestHandler = NQRequestHandler.getInstance(mContext);
            requestHandler.NQRequest(message, "sendPublicKey");

        Log.v("RESULT", "Public KEY JSON from OnStart" + Globals.PUBLIC_KEY);
        //Start Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

The call to NQRequest in the Activity initiates the call to AsyncTask in the Activity. Any help with this? How do I implement a callback in the Activity.java to get method from `OnRequestSuccess();` in the `NQRequest()`? Note: I'm trying to call the method in Activity.java in other multiple Activity.java files

Comment: There is no such thing as a null method. What does it actually do?

Comment: It returns a null value.

Comment: Where is `setContentView()` in `onCreate`?

Comment: There is no Exceptions in your LogCat (log level info)?

Comment: @Rami No exceptions in LogCat just a null value is returned

Comment: you need to wait the called back action from the method onRequestSuccess(JSONArray data) , the AsyncTask services is running the concept like thread, so your activity.class will get null is because the service still running and not completed yet.

Comment: @zeisuke so how would I go about implementing that in the activity.class?

Comment: based on your code i have modify some, you may try it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i modified the structure for your reference.

Modified of requestHandler :-

```
//**** e.g.
class requestHandler extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONArray> {
    // define a caller

    String requester;
    Application caller;
    YourEachActivityClass1 caller1;

    //create a Constructor for caller;
    public requestHandler (Application caller) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         this.caller = caller;
    }

    public requestHandler (YourEachActivityClass1 caller1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         this.caller1 = caller1;
    }

    ///&& method doInBackground
    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... params) {
          .....
          //your process is here
         //custom your returning jsonarray

    try {

    Context context = (Context) params[0];
    Log.i(TAG, "context :"+context.getClass().getSimpleName());

    requester = (Integer) params[1];

    String message = (String) params[2];

    String public= (String) params[3]

        String url = "http://www.someurl.com";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = requestHandlerHelper(params);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);

        entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));
        post.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

        int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength();
        Log.v(TAG, "Content Length DATA" + contentLength);
        char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
        reader.read(charArray);

        String responseData = new String(charArray);
        JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(responseData);

        Globals.PUBLIC_KEY = String.valueOf(jsonResponse);

        return jsonResponse;

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ClientProtocolException: ", e);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException: ", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "IOException: ", e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "JSONException: ", e);
    }
    return null;

    }

    ////&& return JSONArray back to ur activity class here by pass in caller
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonarray) {

        if(requester.equals("IM_Application"))
            caller.onBackgroundTaskCompleted(jsonarray);
        else if(requester.equals("IM_ACTIVITY_1"))
            caller1.onBackgroundTaskCompleted(jsonarray);
    }

}
```

Application.class get ur json object:-

```
public class Application extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            String message = "Hello World from Android";
             new requestHandler(this).execute(getActivity(), "IM_Application", message, "sendPublicKey");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        //your returning result
public void onBackgroundTaskCompleted(JSONArray jsonarray) {
        Log.i("TAG", jsonarray:"+jsonarray);

        if(jsonarray!=null){
            //process your jsonarray to get the Globals.PUBLIC_KEY)here

                    Log.v("onBackgroundTaskCompleted", "Public KEY JSON from OnStart" + Globals.PUBLIC_KEY);
                    //Start Activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);


         }else{
         Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network is unavailable. Request failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }

}

}
```

Gd Luck :)

Comment: But I'm trying to call this in multiple Activity.java files

Comment: Modified your solution a bit. Don't need to state the name of each Activity class

Comment: @Daniel so how is it?

Answer (score 1):

The log from OnStart should return a null value for Globals.PUBLIC_KEY. You have just set an asynchronous task to run to set that value. It has not run yet by the time that log statement executes. You should receive the log input from the

```
Log.v(TAG, "JSON FROM NQRequest" + data);
```

call. That will mostly happen after your activity has finished onCreate, as it is an asynchronous call.

Comment: So how do I get access to that from the Activity.java file? The `Log.v(TAG, "JSON FROM NQRequest" + data);` is in the NQRequestHandler class.

Comment: Well, you can wait for the async request to finish. You can poll on this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus(). However it sounds like you don't want to set this value in an asynctask if you really want to wait for it (because what's the point of async if you're waiting). So I would not use an asynchronous task to set it. Alternatively PostExecute happens on the ui thread so you can use that to set values in your activity if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it works now.

```
public class HQHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {

    public static final String TAG = HQHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    private static HQHandler instance;
    RequestListener requestListener;
    JSONArray requestResult;
    Context mContext;

    public HQHandler(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public static synchronized HQHandler getInstance(Context context) {

        if (instance == null)
            instance = new HQHandler(context);

        return instance;
    }

    public void setRequestListener(RequestListener requestListener) {
        this.requestListener = requestListener;
    }

    public JSONArray getRequestResult() {
        return this.requestResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            String url = "http://www.someurl.com";

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = requestHandlerHelper(params);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters);

            entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"));
            post.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());

            int contentLength = (int) response.getEntity().getContentLength();
            Log.v(TAG, "Content Length DATA" + contentLength);
            char[] charArray = new char[contentLength];
            reader.read(charArray);

            String responseData = new String(charArray);
            JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(responseData);

            return jsonResponse;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "ClientProtocolException: ", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException: ", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "IOException: ", e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "JSONException: ", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray results) {
        if (results != null) {
            requestListener.onRequestSuccess(results);
        } else {
            requestListener.onRequestFailed();
        }
    }

    public interface RequestListener {
        JSONArray onRequestSuccess(JSONArray data);

        void onRequestFailed();
    }

    public JSONArray HQRequest(String... params) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, JSONException {
        JSONArray result;

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network is unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return null;
        }

        HQHandler handler = new HQHandler(this.mContext);
        RequestListener listen = new RequestListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public JSONArray onRequestSuccess(JSONArray data) {
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestFailed() {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Network is unavailable. Request failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        handler.setRequestListener(listen);
        result = this.requestResult = handler.execute(params).get();

        return result;

    }

}
```